# Spotify API authentication error in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, spotify

I quite new to JavaScript and React and I am currently creating an app in ReactNative and am encountering an issue when authenticating with Spotify API. At the moment I'm just trying to fetch the top artists and songs from the API and view them. I'm using expo to test the app and it works fine using my Spotify account *(the same account used for developing the app)*.

I can authenticate and then check the top songs and artists but as soon as I test it on another device with a different Spotify, I can authenticate, although then when I try to view my top songs/artists I get the error **`[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403]`**. It's also worth mentioning that viewing the stats *the very first time works* but anytime after I get that error, even after re-running expo or refreshing.

**Heres my code for the Spotify authentication page..**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { ResponseType, useAuthRequest } from "expo-auth-session";
    import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
    import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
    import { setSpotifyToken, getSpotifyToken } from "../../hooks/spotifyAuth";
    import {
      View,
      Button,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
      SafeAreaView,
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from "react-native";
    import axios from "axios";
    import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
    
    WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
    
    const ConnectSpotifyScreen = () => {
      //Getting hook for sign out button
      const { signOut } = useAuth();
      const { spotifyToken, setSpotifyToken } = useAuth();
    
      //Spotify API information
      const discovery = {
        authorizationEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
        tokenEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      };
    
      const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
        {
          responseType: ResponseType.Token,
          clientId: "ecf0bbd85d8c4456a8551dc30224ee83",
          clientSecret: "SECRET",
          scopes: [
            "user-read-recently-played",
            "user-top-read",
            "user-read-email",
            "user-read-private",
          ],
    
          usePKCE: false,
          redirectUri: "exp://10.0.0.40:19000",
        },
        discovery
      );
    
      //Runs when page is opened, retrieves token from spotify and stores it
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === "success") {
          const { access_token } = response.params;
          setSpotifyToken(access_token);
          console.log("accessToken", access_token);
        }
      }, [response]);
    
      //Page to be rendered
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headerButton}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>Spotify Authentication</Text>
            </View>
            <Image
              style={styles.logo}
              source={require("../../../assets/spotifyLogo.png")}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Button
                light
                disabled={!request}
                title="Connect to Spotify"
                onPress={() => {
                  promptAsync();
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Button onPress={signOut} title="Sign out"></Button>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Note: After authenticating, please sign out and sign back in!
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    //Styling sheet for the page
```

**And heres my code for setting and getting the users Spotify token..**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

//Initially setting the token to null
var spotifyToken = null;

//Function to set the token
function setSpotifyToken(token) {
  spotifyToken = token;
  
}
//Function to get the token
function getSpotifyToken() {
  return spotifyToken;
}

export { setSpotifyToken, getSpotifyToken };
```

I come from a Java background so excuse the bad syntax and poorly written code. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in development have you added the account in the users and access section in the Spotify developer dashboard for you project?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Actually, your answer is not an answer. You should use this comments for this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33249280)